# Review notification appears after suggesting an edit to a tag wiki

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, editing

After editing a tag wiki, the notification that indicates there is an un-reviewed item is visible:

[image]

But you cannot review it, as you suggested the edit.

It will stay there until the item is reviewed by someone else.

This is different than what happens with normal edits, where you do **not** seem to be notified of a review when you edit an answer or question. (as it should be)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> After editing a tag wiki, the notification that indicates there is an un-reviewed item is visible… but you cannot review it, as you suggested the edit.

This is normal. You have the [access to moderator tools](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) privilege *(unlocked at 2k rep on beta sites and at 10k on graduated sites)* so you will get notifications for normal suggested edits excluding yours *and* you should also get notifications for suggested tag wiki edits that are yours. There are no exceptions as these are shown to everyone with the privilege.

You can also get this notification in the edge case where you gain the edit privilege while one of your suggested edits is still pending.

When you suggest a tag wiki edit, you won't be able to review it, that wouldn't make any sense.

> This is different than what happens with normal edits, where you do not seem to be notified of a review when you edit an answer or question. (as it should be)

You also have the privilege to [edit questions and answers](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) without needing approval so neither you nor anyone else will get notifications for these edits since they are applied at once.

Comment: Just to make sure, I assume by "you will get notifications for normal suggested edits excluding yours and you should also get notifications for suggested tag wiki edits that are yours." you mean "you will get notifications for normal suggested edits **including** yours and you should also get notifications for suggested tag wiki edits that are yours.", the only reason you don't, is that in order to get the moderator tools privilege, you will also have the edit without review privilege

Comment: @gandalf3 the only time you get notifications for your edits is when it is a tag wiki as these are shown to everyone with the privilege.

Comment: Right, I think I understand now. I *would* get notified for my other normal edits, except **no one** gets notified, because I have the edit questions and answers without review privilege. So if I had the edit tag wiki without review privilege, I would not get notifications for my own tag wiki edits.

Comment: @gandalf3 you don't get notifications for ___your___ normal edits ever. The only time you get notifications is for other people's normal edits and tag wiki edits including your own.

Comment: I think were saying the same thing different ways..?